Pods Stuck in ContainerCreating State
Problem Statement:
Pods in the Kubernetes cluster are consistently stuck in the ContainerCreating state and are not transitioning to a running state. This issue affects the creation of new pods.
Details:

Current Pod Status:
Running the kubectl get all -n kube-system --kubeconfig admin.kubeconfig command yields the following output:
ubuntu@controller-0:~$ kubectl get all -n kube-system --kubeconfig admin.kubeconfig
NAME                           READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
pod/coredns-76c4db7d5f-k66pd   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          33m
pod/coredns-76c4db7d5f-k7bqm   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          33m

NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.32.0.57   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   33m

NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/coredns   0/2     2            0           33m

NAME                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/coredns-76c4db7d5f   2         2         0       33m

Note: The pods, including coredns, remain in the ContainerCreating state, and no pods are transitioning to the Running state.

Observed Events:
The following events were recorded:
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               39m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kube-system/coredns-76c4db7d5f-k66pd to ip-10-0-1-20
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  4m15s (x159 over 39m)  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to create containerd task: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown

The repeated warning indicates a failure in creating the pod sandbox due to issues with cgroup mountpoints.


Request for Assistance:
Guidance on resolving the FailedCreatePodSandBox error and ensuring proper cgroup configuration would be appreciated.

I guess more info is located in the kubelet logs.
